# How to set gravity to a ViewPager in a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'd like to know if there's exists a way to set gravity to a ViewPager inside a LinearLayout, I tried something like this but it gives me an error.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.fragProjects.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/displayFragment"
        android:name="com.fragProjects.DisplayFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_display" />


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="1"
            android:id="@+id/viewPager">
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/basicFragment"
        android:name="com.fragProjects.BasicFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.2"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_basic" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I need the ViewPager in the middle of both Fragments, and I need them with the same size each one, that's why I tried to use gravity.

If you need the MainActivity where the ViewPager is declared is the following one:

```
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements AdvancedFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    //Number of pages that advanced function ViewPager has.
    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 2;
    //ViewPager that will allow us to swip to access 'shift' advances options.
    protected ViewPager mViewPager;
    //The adapter of previous ViewPager is this.
    protected PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Instantiate ViewPager and PagerAdapter
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        mViewPager.getCurrentItem();

    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }


    /**
          * A simple pager adapter that represents 2 ScreenSlidePageFragment objects, in
          * sequence.
          */
    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    return AdvancedFragment.newInstance("", "Page # 1");
                case 1:
                    //return
                    return AdvancedFragment.newInstance("","");
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }
}
```

If I erase the layout_gravity parameter from the ViewPager and run the application, the ViewPager takes all the screen like we had set its height with 'match_parent', but we didn't set that...

Is it normal in ViewPagers? Does exists a solution for this? 
Greetings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the `android:layout_weight` of your `fragment`. You should add

```
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

to all your `fragment`s and viewpager inside your `LinearLayout`.

> To create a linear layout in which each child uses the same amount of space on the screen, set the android:layout_height of each view to "0dp" (for a vertical layout) or the android:layout_width of each view to "0dp" (for a horizontal layout). Then set the android:layout_weight of each view to "1".

You can learn more about weight in this [Google Layout Weight Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes viewpager will take the entire screen. If you do not want it to take the entire screen. Please have a look at the getPageWidth Method in the corresponding PagerAdapter. Override it and return e.g. 0.75f to have all child pages span only 75% of the ViewPager's width.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:fillViewport="true"
       >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.fragProjects.MainActivity">

    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/displayFragment"
    android:name="com.fragProjects.DisplayFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_display" />


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/basicFragment"
    android:name="com.fragProjects.BasicFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.2"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_basic" />

</LinearLayout>
```